# app service has storage contributor role in blob storage, it is throwing AuthorizationPermissionMismatch exception

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

My App service has a storage contributor role in blob storage, it is throwing AuthorizationPermissionMismatch exception

I've changed roles. App service is added to blob storage as managed identity. with connection string able to upload blobs. Managed identity throwing exception while uploading blob. For GET and DELETE, It is working.

Comment: You need to have the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role added. You many have added Storage Contributor role.

Comment: Yes, it has Storage Blob Data Contributor. Download and Delete blob working.  UploadAsync not throwing error.

Comment: @KishanAnem edit the question with code.

Answer (score 0):

> AuthorizationPermissionMismatch exception

The `AuthorizationPermissionMismatch` exception occurs when the managed identity does not have the necessary permissions to perform the requested operation.

To upload files using managed identity you need the **`storage blob data contributor`** role.

I created an app service with the name **`app9085`** and added the storage blob data contributor role.

**Portal:**

[image]

You can see below my app service has a storage blob data contributor role in blob storage.

[image]

Now you can use the below sample code to upload text files to blob storage using the managed identity.

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.Text;


string accountName = "<Your-storage-account-name>";
string containerName = "<Your-container-name>";
string blobName = "demo.txt"; //your-blob-name
byte[] blobContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello World!!!");

string systemAssignedClientId = "your-client-id";
 
// Create a ManagedIdentityCredential object for the managed identity
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = systemAssignedClientId });

// Create a BlobServiceClient object using the credential and the storage account name
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net"), credential);
var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
blobClient.Upload(new MemoryStream(blobContents), true);
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[DefaultAzureCredential Class (Azure.Identity) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet#examples)

Comment: Yes, it has Storage Blob Data Contributor. Download and Delete blob working.  UploadAsync not throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Storage Blob Data Contributor doesn't have permission to update index tags. we've given a role

Defender for Storage Data Scanner.

Then it starts working. Thanks for the help.